# How can I check that a computer can access a certain URL and send and receive e-mail?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

With Delphi XE2, what is the most reliable method to detect if the computer is able to do the following things?

- reach a specific website with HTTP which does not have a fixed IP address
- send and receive e-mail with any local or remote e-mail client

Comment: There's different ways to look at this too, what if you have an internet connection but the DNS server(s) cannot be accessed?

Comment: @TLama: The question asked for a *reliable* method.  `InternetGetConnectedState()` is not reliable. There are many different ways to get an Internet connection, and `InternetGetConnectedState()` does not handle them all, and can report wrong results even for the ones it does handle.

Comment: @Remy, I've corrected myself [`later on`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684056/most-reliable-method-to-detect-internet-connection?noredirect=1#comment25763710_17684105). I'll rather delete that comment...

Comment: "which does not have a fixed IP address" should rather read "which relies on DNS" or "via a DNS name"

Comment: Being "connected to the Internet" implies none of the things you really want to know, so I've edited your question to avoid that phrase.

Comment: Why would being connected to the Internet not be a prerequisite of accessing a certain URL?

Comment: It is, but 'being' connected is too broad. You cannot check all prerequisites in a reliable way.

Comment: You can be connected to the Internet, but there can be a firewall blocking access just to that certain URL.

Answer (score 4):

There are too many factors involved (type of Internet connection, firewall/router rules, proxies, etc).  The most reliable approach is to simply not try to determine the current state and just attempt the desired operation (perform the actual HTTP request, or the SMTP/POP3/IMAP operation, etc), and just be prepared to react to any errors.  You can detect connection-related errors and prompt the user to check their Internet connection before retrying.

Answer (score 1):

Use `TIdHTTP.Get` and try to download `http://google.com`.

Of course it depends on the definition of being connected to the internet. Sometimes web traffic (port 80) is blocked while other ports are open. Fortunately, nowadays most people are actually allowed to browse the web, since it also provides help with their daily activities. Google is probably one of the least firewalled websites with one of the highest uptimes.

But still, it's a lucky guess. Depending on what you need it for, you might as well just try your thing and see if it works. If not, apparently the computer was not properly connected, even if it could reach Google. :)

[edit]

Because of the discussion. `InternetCheckConnection` is a good alternative too, but it also checks the connection by pinging an actual server.
[MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383996%28VS.85%29.aspx)

> Use the [InternetCheckConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384346%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to check the connection to
>   the Internet. It attempts to ping the server designated by the URL
>   that is passed to the function. If the FLAG_ICC_FORCE_CONNECTION flag
>   is set and the URL is NULL, the function checks to see if there is an
>   entry in the server database for the nearest server. If one exists,
>   the function pings that server

But since this function uses ping, it may be a bit faster than actually retrieving content. On the other hand, many firewalls actively refuse pings.

Comment: I know it sounds far-fetched and hard to believe, but what if some day down the road there is no longer a google.com?

Comment: @JerryDodge That might happen. In that case, you need to distribute a patch for your software. For the time being, you might want to choose a second big domain as a fallback, just to buy you some time when one is down, either temporarily or permanently.

Comment: Or, use something like in TLama's comment which doesn't depend on any resources like that (`InternetGetConnectionState`). OP is asking for "most reliable" method, and I'm sure `InternetGetConnectionState` is more reliable in that case.

Comment: @JerryDodge Very good option indeed, but like I described in my answer (you might want to refresh), 'being connected' is a very broad description of what is going on. That function returning true doesn't mean anything about being able to reach the server you need or do the things you want to do. So like I said, the best solution is just to try the thing that you need to do.

Comment: @Jerry, it is not. Some people say it returns False in case of wireless connection (cannot verify right now). Better might be `InternetCheckConnection` function.

Comment: @JerryDodge but remember Minimum supported server
Windows 2000 Server [desktop apps only]

Comment: `InternetCheckConnection` also pings a server. There is a reason for that. ;)

Comment: Would it increase the reliablity if I use `InternetCheckConnection OR InternetGetConnectionState`?

Comment: I think not. Theoretically, you cannot ping anything without a connection, so for every `true` of `InternetCheckConnection`, `InternetGetConnectionState` should return `true` as well. Of course in practice this might be different and many forum posts seem to suggest false positives or false negatives, so I advise again: just try to do what you need to do and see if it works. Checking a connection gives you no guarantees, just an indication. So to check if you can reach a website, try to download it. To check if you can send mail, try to send the mail.